# Xcode 13: how to pair a watch simulator with iphone simulator

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, simulator

Is pairing of watch sim and iphone sim broken in Xcode 13? I can't pair them.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing `App can run independently of companion iPhone app` to NO in Info.plist.

You can do this easily from XCode by clicking the project, setting the Target to the Watchkit Extension, then changing  `App can run independently of companion iPhone app` from YES to NO.

[image]